# Azure openAI's resource deploy failed

Tags: azure, service, openai-api

My application to access the Azure OpenAI Service has been approved.
I tried to create a new Azure OpenAI resource in my resource group, but failed.
I checked the logs in my subscription, and the page displayed some information as follows:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VJ5GT.png)
Can anyone help me with this issue? I'm looking forward to your assistance.

I tried removing and re-adding the resources, but it still failed.